# .NET MAUI: Customize Shell ContentPage Header

Tags: maui

Is there an opportunity to customize the header bar of a content page?

I want to add some controls after the title:

[image: example]

How can i achieve this?

Here the example code of the page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"        
         x:Class="FluxMobile.Pages.Arrival"
         Title="Arrival">
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label 
        Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The execution of this page is a shell content:

`<ShellContent Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Arrival}" Icon="arrival.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Arrival}" Route="Arrival"  />`

Thank you!

Comment: use a `TitleView`

Comment: I use ToolbarItems from time to time.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856063/net-maui-how-to-place-a-button-inside-the-titlebar