# .NET MAUI - How to place a button in the TitleBar?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, titlebar

In my .NET MAUI project, I want to place a button inside the TitleBar right there:

[image]

The TitleBar itself is generated automatically by setting the Title of the ContentPage.
Does anyone know how to place a button right there?

Comment: use a TitleView

Comment: Expanding on Jason's comment: Maui (by default) uses Shell (rather than NavigationPage). Shell has a simple solution: [Display views in the navigation bar (TitleView)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-7.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar).

Comment: Title bar is different from navigation bar. in the windows context the title bar is where the max and min buttons are located.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested by Jason and Steve, you can use `Shell.TitleView` to achieve the added buttons. For example, the following XAML shows displaying a button in the navigation bar:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="ADD" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Or you can use the `ToolbarItems` as shown below:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="Add_Clicked" />
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

However, it needs a `Navigation` page to show them up. So, you need to modify `MainPage` wrapped by a navigation page:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Comment: The ToolbarItems solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: How do you construct the MainPage if you have dependency injection adding things to the MainPage's constructor? In my case I'm using MVVM and am passing the ViewModel and also a logger. But I don't have them in the App constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot do it with standard navigation (title) bar.** You have to disable the standard navigation bar from your code using the following command in xaml header of your page              `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`

**Then you have to create a custom navigation bar** (using xaml content views, care to use content view, not content pages) with back button and all other you want to place. An example here below

**XAML code for content view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.CustomViews.CustomNavigationBar">

    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HeightRequest="50"
            MaximumHeightRequest="50">
            <ImageButton
                x:Name="btnBack"
                Clicked="btnBack_Clicked"
                Source="backarrow.png"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                MaximumHeightRequest="50"
                MaximumWidthRequest="50"
                Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <Image
                Source="logo.png"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                MaximumHeightRequest="50"
                MaximumWidthRequest="50"
                Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <Label
                x:Name="lblBarTitle"
                TextColor="White"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                FontSize="Title"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
            <ImageButton
                x:Name="btnHome"
                Clicked="btnHome_Clicked"
                Source="homepage.png"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                MaximumHeightRequest="40"
                MaximumWidthRequest="40"
                Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Code behind for content view**

```
public partial class CustomNavigationBar : ContentView
{
    public CustomNavigationBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void btnBack_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    void btnHome_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(TitleText),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(CustomNavigationBar),
    defaultValue: string.Empty,
    BindingMode.OneWay,
    propertyChanged: titleBindablePropertyChanged);

    private static void titleBindablePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (CustomNavigationBar)bindable;
        control.lblBarTitle.Text = newValue.ToString();
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string TitleText
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(TitleTextProperty).ToString(); }
        set { base.SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and finally place the view inside the page you want to use

using for example in a page xaml the following code

**XAML code for your page**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
                <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
            <CustomViews:CustomNavigationBar Grid.Row="0" TitleText="{Binding Settings}"/>

            <!--place here you other stuff of your page....-->

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```